# URI.create() vs new URI()

Tags: java, performance, uri

A `uri` could be created in two ways:

```
//import java.net.URI;
URI uri = new URI("https://www.google.com/");
```

Or,

```
//import java.net.URI;
URI uri = URI.create("https://www.google.com/");
```

I was wondering which is a better practice. I haven't noticed any performance differences and I've read the documentation, however it was a bit difficult to understand. Any insight on this is appreciated.

Comment: Upvote for the question.  I added an "import" statement to disambiguate.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Reading the docs, it differs in the usage.

> Creates a URI by parsing the given string.This convenience factory
>   method works as if by invoking the {@link
>   URI(String)} constructor; any {@link URISyntaxException} thrown by the constructor is caught and wrapped in a new {@link
>   IllegalArgumentException} object, which is then thrown.
>
> **This method is provided for use in situations where it is known that
>   the given string is a legal URI**, for example for URI constants
>   declared within in a program, and so it would be considered a
>   programming error for the string not to parse as such.  The
>   constructors, which throw {@link URISyntaxException} directly, should
>   be used situations where a URI is being constructed from user input or
>   from some other source that may be prone to errors.
>
> @param  str   The string to be parsed into a URI
>
> ```
>  * @return The new URI
>  *
>  * @throws  NullPointerException
>  *          If {@code str} is {@code null}
>  *
>  * @throws  IllegalArgumentException
>  *          If the given string violates RFC&nbsp;2396
>  */
> ```

```
public static URI create(String str) {
    try {
        return new URI(str);
    } catch (URISyntaxException x) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(x.getMessage(), x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh alright, so the main point is how it handles exceptions. I must have missed that in the doc. Thanks

Comment: I wonder by the why how is an IllegalArgumentException better than a URISyntaxException. Weird design decision.

Comment: @RaúlSalinas-Monteagudo Sometimes you need to parse an "untrusted" string to an URI, in which case a "forced" checked exception is not a bad idea. Sometimes you know the string is a valid URI, and with the `create` method you don't need to concern yourself with the checked exception, because you assume there will be none. If there still is one that's a RuntimeException, on the same level as a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 7):

There is no difference because `URI.create` delegates the call to the constructor. The only real difference is that `URI.create(String)` wraps the `URISyntaxException` which the constructor throws (checked exception) into an `IllegalArgumentException` (unchecked exception). So if you don't want to deal with the checked exception it's better to just call `URI.create(String)`.

Here is the piece of code from JDK:

```
public static URI create(String str) {
    try {
        return new URI(str);
    } catch (URISyntaxException x) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(x.getMessage(), x);
    }
}
```