# Scala Option[String] map turns in Iterable

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, iterable

Why does this compile?

```scala
def foo() : Iterable[URI] = {
    Some("")
        .map(URI.create)
}
```

Comment: Is it `java.net.URI`?

Comment: It doesn't *"turn into `Iterable[URI]`"*. The expression `Some("path").map(java.net.URI.create)` gives an `Option[java.net.URI]`. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, I want map to uri and check if that exists, then map to something else

Comment: Your problem isn't reproducible in the form that you've posted It here.

Comment: as long as thats `import java.net.URI`, it should create `Option[java.net.URI]`. The return type of [`URI#create`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31779582/432903) is `URI` itself - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#create(java.lang.String)

Comment: `def existsPath(session: SparkSession, apikey: String, date: String) : Iterable[URI] = {
    val path = dataFramePath(apikey, date)
    Some(path)
      .map(URI.create)
  }` this compiles, why?

Comment: Because, presumably, the `dataFramePath` function is defined in a way that makes this piece of code compile. What's your question? What does this comment have to do with the body of the question?

Comment: Just edited the question, can you check again plz? Can't make more objective than this

Comment: Ah, yeah, this again... That's [because there is an implicit conversion from `Option` to `Iterable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49095685/spark-error-type-mismatch-found-int-string-required-traversableonce/49096160#49096160).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an [implicit conversion called `option2Iterable`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/Option$.html#option2Iterable[A](xo:Option[A]):Iterable[A]) defined directly on `Option`, it converts all `Option[A]` into an `Iterable[A]` with zero or one element.

A much shorter code snippet that demonstrates this somewhat unexpected behavior is the following:

```
(Option(42): Iterable[Int])
```

It will quietly convert `Option` into a `List`, in this case producing a `List(42)`.